# Best strategy in creating users (email + password) with MongoDB and express?

Tags: mongodb, express, authentication, authorization

I'm creating an app, but I am interested to know what the best methodology and packages people use when creating SaaS' to create User accounts.

Currently in mind, using express, mongo and JWT, is this effective? Whats the best system, most used method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends if there is authentication involved. If so, you can use mongodb middleware to generate authentication when creating a new entry automatically.

Also for SaaS, I would recommend GraphQL to reduce "fatty-data" replies.

NoSQL is confusing and counterfactual at first.